# How can I debug a DHCP failure?

Tags: dhcp, vmware-player

I have a new VM installation of Ubuntu 22.04.2 running on VMware Player 17 on Windows 11. All works okay with a static IP, but I can't get DHCP to work as northing seems to received back.

```
mat@devbox:~$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/ens33/00:0c:29:9a:27:bb
Sending on   LPF/ens33/00:0c:29:9a:27:bb
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe24e363f)
DHCPDISCOVER on ens33 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe24e363f)
^C
```

`tcpdump` shows the packet out but nothing in return

```
mat@devbox:~$ sudo tcpdump -i ens33 port 67 or port 68 -e -n -vv
tcpdump: listening on ens33, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:38:23.059861 00:0c:29:9a:27:bb > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:0c:29:9a:27:bb, length 300, xid 0x77a96118, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address 00:0c:29:9a:27:bb
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
        Hostname (12), length 6: "devbox"
        Parameter-Request (55), length 13: 
          Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
          Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
          Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
          NTP (42)
```

Wireshark on the Windows host shows no traffic is received for my VM, but works perfectly fine when I turn on another host:

```
No.    Time        Source       Destination      Protocol  Length  Info
139    9.071516    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.255  DHCP      342     DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x77a96118
140    9.071526    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.255  DHCP      342     DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x77a96118
...
12202  369.907494  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.255  DHCP      344     DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x3a951626
12233  370.931839  192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255  DHCP      342     DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x3a951626
12236  371.034456  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.255  DHCP      370     DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x3a951626
12237  371.034456  192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255  DHCP      342     DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x3a951626
```

My OPNsense DHCP servers shows it sent a `DHCPOFFER`:

```
2023-04-16T11:38:24 dhcpd[68501]    DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.25 to 00:0c:29:9a:27:bb (devbox) via vtnet3_vlan101   
2023-04-16T11:38:23 dhcpd[68501]    DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:9a:27:bb via vtnet3_vlan101
```

How do I debug this further?

Comment: What are the Network Adapter settings of the VM?

Comment: @harrymc Bridged

Comment: I set this in my Ubuntu Machine (Bridged) in Ubuntu, Settings, Network, Wired, IPv4 and there is a Radio button to change from DHCP to Manual and back to DHCP. Try that.

Comment: Does the tcpdump on your VM show *any* traffic being received at all?

Answer (score 0):

How to debug something? Don't change everything all at once. But if you do, be prepared for a day or so checking everything.

Turns out VMware 17.0.1 has a bug in network bridging, see [Workstation Pro/Player latest update 17.0.1 breaks network bridge connectivity](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Workstation-Pro-Player-latest-update-17-0-1-breaks-network/td-p/2954837). Downgrading to 17.0.0 fixed it! (Although my install file was `VMware-workstation-full-17.0.0-20800274.exe` it must have self-updated soon after as reinstalling that file has fixed it).

What it wasn't:

- OPNsense firewall
- Windows firewall
- WiFi AP
- pihole

Comment: I have VMware 17.0.1 here and network is working fine.